# Scrolling menu on a page with fixed content without using frames

Tags: html, css

I have Google Maps included on a page. The left side is meant to be the menu and right side as content.

I want the left side (menu) to scroll, but the right side, (content, map in this case) to not scroll. I don't want to use frames or Javascript.

I want do this with this code:

```
<div  id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed;" ></div>
```

demo: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PHUnW/)

Comment: By Nexs Hax: Add a semicolon after "fixed"?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha The last semicolon is actually not needed, so long as you close the style attribute or CSS rule properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through and tried to reformat and fix some element overlap so that it would be more readable, I hope this helps.

Also, I replaced PHP code with the text: `PHP_INSERT_LOCATION_#` so that I could run it through the validator and make sure I wasn't making any mistakes.

You said the map was not appearing, this is because the map height is `100%` which results in `0` since the only other element of body, `<div id="Menu">`, is `position:absolute;`. Since nothing is setting the height of body, body remains at a height of 0.

To fix the above problem I have added styles of `height:100%;` to html, body, and div.Content to make the above mentioned elements the width of the window, since otherwise the will try to occupy the least possible vertical space.

Also, the Google Maps scripts seem to add `position:relative;` to `<div id="map">` so you will have to add `position:fixed` to the `Content` div instead, see below:

view here: http://jsbin.com/ulalac/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!--
**** PHP_INSERT_LOCATION_1 *****
<?php echo session_id(); ?>
**** PHP_INSERT_LOCATION_2 *****
<?
$ray=mysql_query("select * from rayon");
while($r=mysql_fetch_object($ray)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$r->rayon.'">'.$r->rayon.'</option>
';
}
?>
-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>NN MAP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://nn-gis.com/mp/css/form.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    html,body,div#Content,div#map{height:100%;}
    div#Content{width:100%;position:fixed;}
    /*]]>*/
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://nn-gis.com/mp/js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://nn-gis.com/mp/js/line.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://nn-gis.com/mp/js/zoom.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
<div id="Content">
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>
<div id="Menu">  
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Control Panel</legend> - <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
        <br/>- <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('change.php?sid=PHP_INSERT_LOCATION_1','Reservoirs','height=300, width=460,scrollbars=no');">Change Password</a>
    </fieldset> 
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Active Layers</legend>
        <div class="glossymenu">
            <a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="#" >Points</a>
            <div class="submenu">
                <input type="checkbox" id="intake" onclick="boxclick(this,'intake')" checked="checked"/> <label>Intake</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" id="reservoir" onclick="boxclick(this,'reservoir')" checked="checked"/> <label>Reservoirs</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" id="wps" onclick="boxclick(this,'wps')" checked="checked"/> <label>WPS</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" id="wtp" onclick="boxclick(this,'wtp')" checked="checked"/> <label> WTP</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" id="wwps" onclick="boxclick(this,'wwps')" checked="checked"/> <label>WWPS</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="checkbox" id="wwtp" onclick="boxclick(this,'wwtp')" checked="checked"/> <label>WWTP</label>
                <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Active Lines</legend>
        <form action="">
            <select id="rayon" onchange="line();">
                <option value="rayon">Select Rayon</option>
                <option value="rayon">Qebele</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Projects</legend>
        <form action="">
            <select id="countyLocation" onchange="zoom();search();">
                <option value="center">Select Title</option>
                <!--
                PHP_INSERT_LOCATION_2
                -->
            </select>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Tables</legend>
            - <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('data/show.php?page=Reservoirs','Reservoirs','height=600, width=660,scrollbars=no')">Reservoirs</a>
            <br/>
            - <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('data/show.php?page=TBL_MAIN_INV','TBL_MAIN_ING','height=600, width=1024,scrollbars=no')">Main investment</a>
            <br/>
            - <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('data/show.php?page=TBL_MAIN_INV_BID','linkname','height=600, width=960,scrollbars=no')">Bidding Procedures</a>
            <br/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Analysis</legend>
        - <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('backup.php','backup','height=600, width=660,scrollbars=no')">Backup Data</a>
        <br/>
        <br/>  
        <br/>
    </fieldset>              
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok. Thanks for answer.. when i put this tag map stopped working <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Comment: i want fixed content side.. want to scroll menu side.

Comment: @brio there I think I have it

Comment: small problem: How can i balance this div s?:((

Comment: @brio that is probably a whole other problem. I would guess it has to do with the styles inherited from http://nn-gis.com/mp/css/form.css . best of luck to you though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is what you want:

```
<div id="Content" style="position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px; ">
    <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%;" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding style="height:100%; overflow:scroll;" to the menu div and "overflow:hidden;" to the body :)